# how to concatenate two columns in yii2 activerecord?

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

I am new to developing in yii2 (and yii). I have a query that returns name and last name of customers along with other columns. I am using activeDataProvider to display the records in a table but I need the name and lastname be displayed in one table column.

What I want to know is:

```
1. how do I concatenate the columns in yii2 activerecord?
2. How do I display the columns in one table columns made gridView?
```

below is what I have tried that none works:

```
1. $query->select(['customer.*', 'fullname'=>concat('customer.name'," ",'customer.lastname')]);
2. 'dataProvider' => $model['dataProvider'],
                'columns' => [
                  'id',
                  'name'.' '.'lastname',
                  'customer_orders',
                  'created_at:datetime'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **GridView** like below.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
           'attribute' => 'name',
           'value' => function ($model) {
               return $model->name . ' ' . $model->lastname;
           }
        ]
        'customer_orders',
        'created_at:datetime'
    ]
]) ?>
```

Refer [Yii2 GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html)